# How to display variables in Taglist window in vim

Tags: vim, taglist

I am using Taglist plugin in vim. In the taglist window i can see tags like namespaces, classes, struct, function but not variables. I saw a screenshot(attached below) on Taglist website which had this info. I am using Vim 7 and Exuberant Ctags 5.8, and i have generated my ctags using this command

```
ctags --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/images/taglist_c.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a variable `s:tlist_def_cpp_settings` in Taglist plugin (.vim/plugin/taglist.vim) that defines which elements are shown by default.

I extended it to:

`let s:tlist_def_cpp_settings = 'c++;n:namespace;v:variable;d:macro;t:typedef;' . 
                              \ 'c:class;g:enum;s:struct;u:union;f:function;m:member;' .
                                 \ 'p:prototype'`

According to taglist manual you can also define `tlist_cpp_settings` in your `.vimrc` with similar value.

For other languages different variables exist.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the Taglist plugin shows only the variables which have file
scope. It does not show variables which have only function scope.

For a quick test just add a variable of any type at the start of your source
file, save the source file, set cursor into the taglist window 
and press u to update taglist. Now this variable should appear in the taglist window.
This works for my C files.

By the way:

> ... and i have generated my ctags using this command
>
> ctags --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++

Do you mean that you generate your own tags file for the taglist plugin 
using these ctags options?
To my knowledge taglist uses its own ctags options and generates a temporary
tag file. The user has no influence on the ctags options and the tags file.

Comment: Use let tlist_cpp_options to set options on how taglist executes ctags. (:help taglist-extend) As answered, it executes ctags itself on the fly and shows results that way.  It doesn't use a ctags file.